# Delphi 5 and ADO

Tags: ms-access, delphi-5

I thought I'd finished with Delphi 5, but my "customer" wants some highly-specialised reporting and like a muggins I agreed to do it.  The databases are MS Access (2000).   I have used a fairly standard ADOConnection -> ADOQuery or ADOTable approach to connecting to the databases.  There are three in total, so three ADOConnections.   Works a treat on my Windows 7 machine.   However, when I install the program onto the target client PC (also Win7) and try to run it, I get the dreaded "Cannot open table MSysAccount" error.  I know from research that this is in System.MDW and looking at this system database shows me that the table doesn't exist.  The MDW database date is sometime in 2012.

There is nothing I have Googled which works (I've tried three possibilities), and Microsoft don't seem to offer a solution.   There is apparently a registry fix that will stop the database engine from looking for the MSysAccount table, but I cannot find which variable is involved and what to do with it.

Can anyone either guide me with a fix for this or, perhaps, a schema for this table in the system database, please?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the one thing that wasn't suggested was to create MDBs with the same name and import the data.   When I create the new MDB it automatically creates the appropriate MDW tables (or entries, who knows?) and the problem goes away, at least well enough for my purposes.  I've tested the tables involved against the other applications that use them and there seems to be no problem, presumably because they were created by the same user who created the previous versions.